# How to limit number of entries to transfer from one internal table to another

Tags: split, abap

I want to  extract a database to an internal table, using SELECT and then save the extraction locally, using GUI_DOWNLOAD.
However, each file can only have 1 million entries and the extraction comes out with more entries than that.

What is the best way to split the internal table into small tables that contain maximum of 1 million entries. Or to save 1 million entries at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use the `PACKAGE SIZE` addition to split it already on the database level.

For example

```
REPORT ZZZ.

DATA: gt_baldat TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF baldat WITH EMPTY KEY.
CONSTANTS: gc_max_package_size TYPE i VALUE 1000000.

START-OF-SELECTION.

SELECT * FROM baldat 
  CLIENT SPECIFIED 
  PACKAGE SIZE gc_max_package_size
  INTO TABLE gt_baldat.
* call GUI_DOWNLOAD
  WRITE / lines( gt_baldat ).
ENDSELECT.
```

Comment: And if I do this, how can I select the remaining entries from the database? Basically how can I limit the selection based on the what has previously been selected?

Comment: The remaining entries will be selected automatically. You do not have to do anything specifically to achieve it. If there is less than a million entries in the table, all of them will be selected anyway and there will be just one package. The second question is a question I do not understand. Do you use different criteria for different packages?!?!

Comment: The second question was the same as the first one. You answered my question anyway. Thank you very much

Comment: You are very welcome. Upvoting it also would be highly welcome. ;) Best regards.

Comment: It's not the best example to choose BALDAT because it's a Data Cluster Table "[with one cluster made of multiple rows](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abenexport_data_cluster_indx.htm)" ;) (i.e. its content is compressed and rows must be kept together to be decoded ; instead, prefer any other type of table...)

Comment: @SandraRossi Was just an example. I have chosen it because usually there is a lot of records there.